# How to manage back button with multiple screens in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, back

If there is some way how to manage back button in Libgdx?

for example in Andengine I have implemented this like that:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {  
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {          
          switch (currentScene) {
               case SPLASH:
                   break;
               case MENU:
                   Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
                   break;
               case WORLDMENU:
                       start(MENU);
                       break;
...
...
    }
  }
}
```

I don't have idea how to do it here, because ApplicationListener has only create, show, render...
I tryed this:

```
if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Keys.BACK)){
    new ScreenChangeTask(MyScreen.SPLASH);
}
```

but it still closes my application.

FYI: I have `class Controller extends Game` and I use `public void setScreen (Screen screen)` to switch between screens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to do this properly you need to tell LibGDX to catch the back key:

```
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

You should do this somewhere early in the application. And set it to false when you want the user to be able to use the back key.

Comment: An alternative to setting it to false is to just call Gdx.app.exit() when you do actually want to allow the user to quit.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. But I have one more question: `if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK)){
         System.out.println("Back key was pressed");
         new Timer().schedule(new ScreenChangeTask(MyScreen.SOME_SCREEN), 1);
  }` - I put this code in render method. And when I press Back button it switches back to another screeen, and in that screen it swithes back to another, because this peace of code is triggered several times till I remove finger. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: All you need to do is use a boolean variable in your if statement, and then set the boolean to false if the key is pressed so the next game loop it doesn't enter it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also can make static method which calculates time difference between last click and current click (return boolean) and if for example is passed 0.5sec than can click, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

set

```
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

then implement below code on keyUp...

```
    @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {          
              switch (currentScene) {
                   case SPLASH:
                       break;
                   case MENU:
                       Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
                       break;
                   case WORLDMENU:
                           game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game)); //MenuScreen is your class Screen
                           break;
            return false;
        }
    }
    }
```

Hope this will help you